# HttpClient's pooled connectionManager to recover from server closed connection

Tags: connection, httpclient, pool

When a pooled connectionManager is used, a connection in the pool may be disconnected by server when it is idle for sometime, but the object may stay in the pool before evicted, and may be used later by an http request. Then it will fail with IOException.

How do we recover from this. I can only think of retry the http request. Is there a way the connectionManager can detect this and discard the connection? (BTW, evict thread cannot guarantee it.)

Answer (score 0):

As I dug into PoolingHttpClientconnectionManager and linked HttpClient 4 source code, I found the connection was checked with isStale() before being used. Two interesting points:

1. The pool keeps connection objects, but not necessarily connected. If the borrowed connection object is disconnected, it will reconnect.
   I had a connectionPool implementation in which I destroy a disconnected object and borrow from pool again. All newly created objects in the pool are initially connected.
   Somehow I like their approach to mine.
2. The isStale() implementation is interesting, it tries to read from the socket inputStream with 1 millisecond timeout, and claim it stale if -1 returned or any exceptions except SocketTimeoutException.
   This isStale() is checked every time when using a connection. I'm not fan of it. I'd prefer the approach to retry sending request if failed, because most of time the connection should be good and doesn't need isStale() check.